# CDK ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService multiple ports

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

My container has two ports 8080 & 60000, I would like to expose both except that 8080 is exclusively for the health check. So port 60000 get requests forwarded from the application load balancer while port 8080 handles health checks. Currently I have the portMapping defined:

```
const container = new ContainerDefinition(this, 'TestContainerDef', {
  image: ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(imageRepo),
  taskDefinition,
  containerName: 'test',
  logging: logDriver,
  portMappings: [
    {
      hostPort: 60000,
      containerPort:60000,
    },
    {
      hostPort: 8080,
      containerPort: 8080,
    },
  ]
})
```

And the service defined as:

```
const fargate = new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
  this,
  `TestService`,
  {
    assignPublicIp: true,
    listenerPort: 60000,
    cluster: cluster,
    cpu: 256,
    desiredCount: 1,
    memoryLimitMiB: 512,
    publicLoadBalancer: true,
    taskDefinition,
    ...,
  }
)
```

And the health check defined like this:

```
fargate.targetGroup.configureHealthCheck({
  path: '/health',
  interval: Duration.minutes(5),
  port: '8080',
})
```

But the containers get shut down after some time for failing the health check. What am I missing?

Comment: I would go into the AWS console and verify the security groups the CDK is creating. The ECS task should allow incoming requests at ports `8080` and `60000` from the load balancer's security group. Given your code, I'm not entirely sure the CDK is going to open port `8080` in the security group.